# Хочу выставить текст на центр

Tags: html, css, текст

Хочу,чтобы было как на 1-ой картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выходит это:
[image: Выходит это:]

(Знаю. Вопрос глупый)

Comment: А где код.Добавте html css код

Comment: Да нормальный вопрос. text-align:left  блоку с текстом и подогнать margin. Если хочешь осуществить вертикальное выравнивание используй flexbox.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /*Центрирование по горизонтали*/
    align-items: center;     /*Центрирование по вертикали */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border:1px solid black">
    <span class="inner" style="border:1px solid red">
        Центрированный<br>Элемент
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: а вообще это список;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
 text-align: left;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 padding: 50px 20px;
 }
  .outer ul{
 list-style:none;
  }
 .outer a{
 text-decoration:none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Главная магазин</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>

<li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```